# Facebook how to differentiate between promoted post and un-published post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are using page_id/promotable_post to get the post made by the brand. This endpoint returns both promoted posts and unpublished or "Dark" posts.

We are interested in getting only the unpublished/dark post and not the promoted post since those come via the real-time webhook also.

We can see the documentation mentioning the following two parameters,

```
include_inline=true&is_published=false
```

Would it be right to assume that specifying this would stop promoted posts?

Comment: That would be for requests you make yourself, but you can not specify such parameters for a webhook setup AFAIK.

Comment: @CBroe Not for web-hook for the promotoble post end-point only to get the un-published posts and not boosted posts.

Comment: Well then you should be able to easily test it, no?